# Matplotlib animation update X-axis limit doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I want automatically update the X-axis datetime limit. When using `set_xlim` in the `__init__` function it works, but the same command has no effect when used in the  `__call__` function.

**Code:**

```
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def data():
    target_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    n=0
    while True:
        target_time = target_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
        x = target_time
        y=np.sin(n)*10
        yield (x, y)
        n+=0.05
        time.sleep(2)

class Update(object):
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.x=[datetime.datetime.now()]
        self.y=[0]
        self.line, = ax.plot(self.x, self.y, 'k-')
        self.ax = ax

        # Set up plot parameters
        now = self.x[0]
        minxlim = now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
        maxxlim = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
        print(minxlim)
        self.ax.set_xlim(left=minxlim, right=maxxlim) # it's works
        self.ax.set_ylim(-15, 15)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.counter=0

    def init(self):

        self.line.axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
        return self.line,

    def __call__(self, args):

        self.counter += 1
        i = self.counter
        win = 60
        imin = max(0, i - win)
        self.x.append(args[0])
        self.y.append(args[1])
        xdata = self.x[imin:i]
        ydata = self.y[imin:i]
        self.line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
        self.line.set_color("red")
        now = xdata[-1]
        minxlim = now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
        maxxlim = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
        self.ax.set_xlim(left=minxlim, right=maxxlim) #  not work
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()

        return self.line,

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ud = Update(ax)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, ud, frames=data,init_func=ud.init,interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[Github link](https://github.com/fongzii/python_study/blob/master/Animation)

When running this, it still looks like the initial X axis, even though the limits should change each frame.

Comment: You should write the code in this post instead of linking GitHub

Comment: You need to post your code with the question itself, not as an external github link. This way, potential helpers viewing your question will all see the same code and reproduce the same problem when they try to answer, as opposed to a github repo where the code can change anytime (or disappear altogether). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry for my poor English,when I post code to here it tell me "it's mainly code question,need more details",I try my best to post details but still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blitting changes the content of the axes, not the decorators. This means that those decorators like ticks and labels stay the same throughout.
Since your animation is pretty slow anyways there is no need for blitting. So you may just turn it off,

```
FuncAnimation(..., blit=False)
```